# with-redefs not replacing valid Compojure route function call in clojure.test

Tags: unit-testing, clojure, compojure, ring

I want to test my Compojure endpoints and see that the required method is called. However, `with-redefs-fn` is not replacing the method.

Test method-

```
(ns project-name.handler-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
        [project-name.handler :as handler :refer [retrieve-records test-handler]]
        [ring.mock.request :as mock]))

(deftest fn-handler-routes
  (with-redefs-fn {#'handler/retrieve-records (fn [arg] :test)} 
    (let [response {:status 200 :body :test}] 
    (let [mock-handler (test-handler)]
    (is (= response (mock-handler (mock/request :get "/records/name"))))))))
```

I am guessing routes are static, and thus the method fires and returns actual data instead of calling the redefined function. `test-handler` is a failing attempt to try to circumvent -- it fires okay, but does not use `with-redefs` and returns repo data.

Pertinent Source Code-

```
(defn retrieve-records [arg] (repo/get-records arg))

(defroutes routes
  (GET "/" [] (resource-response "index.html" {:root "public"}))
  (context "/records" []
    (GET "/name" [] (retrieve-records :lastname)))
  (resources "/"))

(defn test-handler []
  (-> #'routes wrap-reload))
```

**Related Issues**

I suspect a similar underlying issue as [this SO question about Midje](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28549878/3100284) but I am using `clojure.test` and not `midje`.

This question is different from [a very similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34418001/3100284) in that the Compojure route is legitimate and I want to return something in the `:body`, not just test the status (already tried that answer).

This question is different from [an integration test question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12271054/3100284) in that it is a handler unit test, though probably the same underlying issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why won't you use `with-redefs` instead of `with-redefs-fn`?

Comment: Second argument to `with-redefs-fn` should be a function, not actual code. See example in the doc: https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-redefs-fn

Comment: So I am not 100% sure of what you are suggesting. If you could drop it in an answer, I will give it a try and can accept as answered.

Comment: I mean that `with-redefs-fn` should be used as follows: `(with-redefs-fn {<map-entries>} (fn [] <your-body>)`. Now you are using it like `(with-redefs-fn {<map-entries>} <your-body>)` (i.e. wrapping body with `fn` is missing). Doesn't this cause the problem?